# Automatically starting oneshot service on bootup

Tags: systemd

I have a oneshot service which I want to start at boot time on rhel 7.4.

I understand that `"chkconfig --add"` is one way to achieve this. But it requires the startup script to be present in

> /etc/init.d directory

For non-oneshot services, I understand that the "Restart=" option could be used in the systemd service file.

If I try to set `Restart=always` for a oneshot service, it doesn't work. Oneshot service needs `"Restart=no"`.

Is there any way I can start a oneshot service upon boot without having the script in

> /etc/init.d directory

Comment: I've added an answer. Note the `Type` `oneshot`.

Answer (score 1):

"systemctl enable" takes care of starting any service, be it oneshot or other.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, since we have not mentioned your Systemd service, here an example:

Example filename:

```
/etc/systemd/system/my-startup-script.service
```

Example content:

```
[Unit]
Description=My startup script
#After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/root/my-startup-script.sh
RemainAfterExit=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After that, just enable it:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable my-startup-script
```

In this way you have enabled your service. So, after every reboot, your oneshot service (or whatever normal service) will be executed.

That's all my friend!